# AIR 3D Amazon render server with NVIDIA Tesla GPU not working

Tags: air, 3d, nvidia, windows-server-2012, tesla

We have an Adobe AIR Stage3D application that renders 3D objects and lets the user view them. We want to create a render server for fallback if the user has no Flash installed. The easiest would be to use the same codebase to generate 3D images on a windows server. We wanted to test this fallback on Amazon servers with NVIDIA Tesla M2050 GPU-s and Windows 2012 to see the performance. Unfortunately only software render mode was available with no access to the gpu. The driverInfo was: Software Hw_disabled=unavailable
Also we tried running the process as a service in Session 0 as a background service with the help of:  http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunAdobeAIRAsAService.html
but we had no luck. NVIDIA Tesla M2050 GPUs with TCC drives allow GPU usage in Session 0. I tried to update the driver to the latest but still no luck.

Any idea how we could test Adobe AIR 3D capabilities as a service on an Amazon server, or why it is not working:

The configuration was:

- Window 2012 Server Standard 64
- 2db Intel Xeon X5570 2.93Ghz
- 22 GB Ram
- 2db NVIDIA Tesla M2050
- Adobe AIR 3.8

Thank You

Comment: I believe the only access to the GPU from session 0 with Tesla and TCC is compute based not render.